# Increment number when Date changes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good day,

I have a small problem. I have two cells:

B35 is a date cell with mmm-yy
and
B37 is a number with no decimal places.

I would like a formula that increments B37 by 1 when ever the date changes, i.e 
B35: Mar-13
B37: 4
when B35 is inputted as Apr-13, then B37 changes to 5 automatically.

I hope I was able to put my problem through clearly.
Thank You.

Comment: You'll need vba in the `worksheet_changes` event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B35")) Is Nothing Then
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Range("B37").Value = Range("B37").Value + 1
      Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Thank You